# jQuery - calculate average from span tags and output in a text field

Tags: jquery, average, jquery-calculation

I just started with jQuery and I'm having some troubles. I need to get a number between span tags, and output an average in an input field. Only the spans with a value different from 0 are valid , otherwise they should be ignored. Also the numbers can change anytime and the average must update without page reloading.

RELEVANT HTML

```
<div>
    <span class="pm_label">5</span>
</div>
<div>
    <span class="pm_label">10</span>
</div>
<div>
    <span class="pm_label">0</span>
</div>

<input type="text" name="average" class="average" value="">
```

NON WORKING JS:

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function($) {

    var sum = 0; 
    var nums = 0;

     $('.pm_label').each(function(){

        var value = $(this).html()

        if(value != 0) {

            sum += value;
            nums++;
        }
     });

     var avg = sum / nums ; 

     $('#average').val(Math.floor(avg));
     console.log(avg);

});
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get you started:

```
var total = 0,
    valid_labels = 0,
    average;

$('.pm_label').each(function () {
    var val = parseInt(this.innerHTML, 10);
    if (val !== 0) {
        valid_labels += 1;
        total += val;
    }
});

average = total / valid_labels;
$('.average').val(average);
```

Here's a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/F6tsQ/4/)**

You could make this into a function and call it whenever the `span`s' value change.

Comment: Nothing I get a NaN inside the text input. It must be because of something else, maybe because these span values are generated from some jQuery UI sliders, and it's somehow conflicting. Anyway your solution obviously works so I'll accept that. Thanks

Comment: Thanks. The key here is `parseInt`--it converts the raw string values from the `span`s to integers.

Answer (score 1):

modify ur test box to have an ID

```
<input type="text" name="average" class="average" value="">
```

to

```
<input type="text" ID ="average" name="average" class="average" value="">
```

or select using name attribute

```
$('input[name="average"]').val("");


use sum += parseInt(value);   instead of  sum += value;
```